# Run Go scripts in local vagrant machine

Tags: go, vagrant, vagrantfile

I want to run Go scripts with Vagrant. 
When I do vagrant up, and run the command 'go version'
I do not see any Go installed and am told that

```
The program 'go' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```

`
So I did install it and now it's running with simple scripts like fmt.Println()

Then my question is...

I have a repository with a lot of code in Go.
And need to run this in Virtual Machine with Vagrant.

Then what would be the best way to run the scripts that were worked on outside of Vagrant VM
because when I do `vagrant up` I do not see anything so I had to install Go.

Comment: [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23234382/720999).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't want to deploy via source and `go run`. The `run` command is mostly just a connivence wrapper that builds and executes your binary in one step. There's a lot that it can't do. Compile your code, and run the binary.

If the deployment target is a different os/architecture, there's nothing wrong with building the executable in the VM, just make sure it's has Go. You can also cross-compile you code if you don't have any dependency on cgo, which may be easier.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it makes sense.  Another dumb question if you don't mind. I just started learning.  I know how to compile and generate the binary file. Then is there any way that I can compile in a different os like Mac and transfer the binary file to local vagrant vm? It has go installed but I do not want to write everything again in the vagrant environment again. To summarize what is the best way to integrate the outside Go code into Vagrant environment.

Comment: Yes, you can cross-compile go (http://dave.cheney.net/2013/07/09/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go-1-1). I don't understand what you mean by "write everything again...", the code is the same regardless of where you write it. Just copy the files into the VM, pull from version control, etc.; but that's not within the scope of a Go programming question.